# Will Firebase firestore offline persistence work with offline electron js application?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with electron js and angular. And I want to use firestore database.

As far as I know, firestore is enabled with auto persistency.

First of all, will it work with my desktop application (node base / electron + angular)?

Second, let's say my application mostly works offline. And I need to do certain CRUD operations during these uncertain offline runtimes. So, if the first question's answer is yes, can I perform above operations in offline mode and will it sync as soon as the system goes online?

Third and last, if the answer to the second question is yes, then what if my system shutdowns that is desktop?

I will be glad for a detailed explanation of answers and a detailed explanation of how persistence works and is provided.

I am new to this channel. Please don't mind if I ask my question informally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase saves all offline actions to essentially an internal transaction pool for offline persistence. When Firebase does connect back online, it will attempt to sync all previous changes including transactions, document updates, and deletes.

The issue is the local pool wasn't made for extended offline use and over time, depending on how much data, it can slow the app down to handle all the data.
I've heard it should behave fine if the device is offline for about a month or two for general use but it might be better to support your offline app with an offline-first database such as [**PouchDB**](https://blog.couchbase.com/introduction-offline-data-storage-sync-pouchdb-couchbase/) or [**NeDB**](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) and sync changes with Firebase as needed.

Comment: I would recommend to try out RxDB. It has a plugin for firestore<->RxDB replication which makes it easy to have a local database that can be queried and is really offline first. See https://rxdb.info/replication-firestore.html